# How can I get an array of numbers from the user and show the numbers with formatting?

Tags: output-formatting, output, input

Suppose that I have to print the following lines:

Number 1 is 5
Number 2 is 6
Number 3 is 7
Number 4 is 8
Number 5 is 9

Now, if I were programming in *C*, I would have run the following code :

```
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
{printf("Number %d is %d \n",i,i+4);}
```

`Print["Number %d is %d", i, i + 4]` doesn't work in *Mathematica* (and yes, I am aware of it).

Moreover, in $C$, I can scan input like this:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{printf("Enter Number %d: ",i);
scanf("%d",&Scanned[i])};           \* Where Scanned[i] is the Array Storing Values of the Numbers *\
```

I tried

```
For[i = 0, i < 5, i++, Scanned[i] = Input["Enter the Number %d: ", i]]
```

But it didn't work (I guess %d is not recognizable by Mathematica).

So how would I implements these tasks in Mathematica?

(I apologize if this question is of very low level, but I searched a lot for it, and didn't get an appropriate answer to my query.)

Comment: Take a look at `StringTemplate` or `StringForm` to learn about templates syntac in Mathematica. The way to go is `Do + Print + StringTemplate`. You may also be interested in column.

Comment: See also: [11305](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11305/5478)

Comment: I would add see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134610/38205) on avoiding for loops--just generally good knowledge for people new to Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

```
StringForm["Number `` is ``", #, # + 4] & /@ Range[5] // Column
```

[image]

```
Print[StringForm["Number `` is ``", #, # + 4]] & /@ Range[5];
```

[image]

```
n = 1; While[n < 6, 
 Print[StringForm["Number `` is ``", n, 
   InputString["Enter number " <> ToString[n++]]]]]
```

[image]