# How to insert text in Table

Tags: list-manipulation

I have

```
Table[{i^2, "mod",  i + 1, "=", Mod[i^2, i - 1]}, {i, 3, 4}]
```

which gives me

```
{{9, mod, 4, =, 1}, {16, mod, 5, =, 1}}
```

But I want to get

```
{{9 mod 4 = 1}, {16 mod 5 = 1}}
```

How can I get rid of the commas in the output? I can drop the first comma in `Table` after `i^2` but when dropping other commas things get messy. What am I doing wrong? What are the rules? I can't find anything in `Help`.

Comment: You can use methods presented in: [11305](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11305/5478), does it fit your needs?

Comment: Yes, it helps. Thank you!